# I am trying to implement a leader board system in my dice rolling game but all my attempts have failed, is there a way to do this?

Tags: python, pickle, leaderboard, shelve

```
import shelve
import pickle
scoreFile = shelve.open('score.txt')
username = 'User1'
def updateScore(newScore):

  if('score' in scoreFile):
    score = scoreFile['score']
    if(newScore not in score):
      score.insert(0, newScore)

    score.sort()
    ranking = score.index(newScore)
    ranking = len(score)-ranking
  else:
    score = [newScore]
    ranking = 1

  if len(score) >5:
    del(score[0])
  else:
    pass

  print(score)
  print(ranking)

  scoreFile['score'] = score
  places = {'first':'user',
  'second': 'user',
  'third': 'user',
  'fourth': 'user',
  'fifth' : 'user'
  }

  if ranking ==1:
    places['first']= username
  elif ranking==2:
    places['second'] = username
  elif ranking ==3:
    places['third'] = username
  elif ranking == 4:
    places['fourth'] = username
  elif ranking ==5:
    places['fifth'] = username
  else:
    print("not on leaderboard")

  filename = "names.txt"
  file = open(filename, 'wb')
  pickle.dump(places, file)

  return ranking

newScore = int(input("New HighScore: \n"))
updateScore(newScore)
```

I've tried to use pickle and shelve as you can see above but the dict does not save, I'm sure there are better ways of going about this. All I need to do is relate the points of the winner and the place of the user and the name of the user in one go on a leader board for the top 5. If anyone can help thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know shelve or pickle but it seems like you are just opening the file. At no point you are saving the changed data.

Comment: Since the data appears to be just a simple dict, why not use json?

Comment: I currently do not know much about json, I think if I do some research on it it is possible. Is there an easier way to do it i.e. csv (I haven't learnt this either)